# Why is there no operator as syntactically graceful as the 'as' keyword that also throws an exception?

Tags: c#, .net

I find the 'as' keyword to be incredibly elegant, but there's almost no situation where I want a boxing/unboxing operation to return to null.

The default cast syntax is, by comparison, pretty ugly, and the difference often causes programmers to treat 'as' as sugar for the default behaviour.

Why is there no equivalent as I've described?

Comment: Because the default cast syntax is more familiar? It's seen in numerous C-style languages, whereas the `as` keyword as far as I know (for its purpose) only makes an appearance in C#. There doesn't appear to be a *very compelling* reason to add a language construct that functions identically to something that already exists and is tried and tested.

Comment: The fact of using cast in any form should make you to consider alternative approaches. Casts/type checks are often can be avoided by using generic code or proper class/interface design...

Answer (score 0):

To just compare types you can use the [is operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/scekt9xw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (depending on your scenario)